# Verify with mocks an error message where result can change based on id

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit4

So I've got some unit tests where I'm mocking a number of objects, and using those to write tests.

I'm setting the mock objects using `anyInt()` argument matcher. I want to verify a method called `displayErrorMessage(String errorMsg)`. This method accepts a string, and outputs it into the GUI. The String it accepts is formatted before being sent to the display method with the relevant member Id.

I want to use the argument matcher again in a String format to pass the correct error message to the verify statement.

```
String.format("Member %d cannot borrow at this time.", anyInt());
```

I know `anyInt()` returns zero. I can just manually verify the displayErrorMessage() assuming this, but that seems incorrect.

Current test code:

```
@Test
public void borrowingRestrictedWhenCardSwipedHasExceededFineLimit() throws Exception {
    when(memberDAO.getMemberByID(anyInt())).thenReturn(member);
    when(member.hasReachedFineLimit()).thenReturn(true);

    ctl.initialise();
    ctl.cardSwiped(anyInt());

    String errorMessage = "Member %d cannot borrow at this time.";
    errorMessage = String.format(errorMessage, anyInt());

    verify(ui).displayErrorMessage(errorMessage);
}
```

This verify would work in this situation:

`verify(ui).displayErrorMessage("Member 0 cannot borrow at this time.");`

If I'm approaching this incorrectly, whats a better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you call an actual method with a matcher? Using anyInt() will not miraculously actually test your method with any int possible. It doesn't make sure that it will work for any int. It's a matcher that matches any int, so you can use it to verify that some method was called with any int - if you don't care what int it was. In your case, you should simply put a REAL number there and check your expected message with that. What numbers you need to test for is depending on your code.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz well it's a mocked member object. It doesn't matter what ID it gets set to. I have to set the member mock as having fines in the first place, in the second "when".

Comment: ctl is not mocked (otherwise the initialize call would be nonsense). So, yes, you can prepare your mocks to return the same member for any id, true, but for the actual call you should actually GIVE an actual id. Calling a real method with anyInt() doesn't make any sense. Call `ctl.cardSwiped( 42 )` and check for the apropriate message. Your mocks will accept 42 (because 42 is an anyInt() ) and return the member which has reached the fine limit.

Comment: `ctl` is not mocked, but it's constructor is fed purely with mock classes for test purposes. So no real data involved. I take it in this case I should just avoid `anyInt()`, and use actual, specific ints? Even if these ints don't correspond to any actual data in the real program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this explanation is a little bit longer, here an answer...

anyInt() is used as an argument when a matching is wanted. There are two main cases for that:

```
when( myMock.someMethod( anyInt() ).thenReturn( x );
```

This makes myMock return "x" whenever someMethod is called - regardless what the actual int in question was. So...

```
myMock.someMethod( 12 ) // will return x
myMock.someMethod( -180 ) // will return x
myMock.someMethod( 42 ) // will return x
// etc. ANY int parameter you give, will lead to x, since you told Mockito so in the when statement.
```

The other way to use it, is to verify:

```
verify(myMock, times(1)).someMethod( anyInt() );
```

This will only throw an error if someMethod was NEVER called with any int. If it was called with 12 or -180 or 42 or 1 or 2 or 3, etc. this will be fine (as long as it was called exactly once - not once per int, but once total).

Of course anyInt() has an int value, since it must be put into an int's place, but I would totally ignore that value and never rely on it.

When calling the real method in the end, you should NOT use anyInt() but a real value, since this will give you more control. In your case, I would NOT use anyInt() at all, to be honest:

```
@Test
public void borrowingRestrictedWhenCardSwipedHasExceededFineLimit() throws Exception {
    when(memberDAO.getMemberByID(42)).thenReturn(member);
    when(member.hasReachedFineLimit()).thenReturn(true);

    ctl.initialise();
    ctl.cardSwiped(42);

    String errorMessage = "Member %d cannot borrow at this time.";
    errorMessage = String.format(errorMessage, 42);

    verify(ui).displayErrorMessage(errorMessage);
}
```

Why? Because this way you can be sure, that when `ctl.cardSwiped` is called, it will actually use the parameter for the `memberDAO.getMemberByID` call. With anyInt() you cannot. For example, there could be an error in  `ctl.cardSwiped`:

```
memberDao.getMemberById( parameter - 1);
```

With `anyInt()` in your when, your result would still be the member.

You know that your test case will give 42 as a parameter and ONLY when 42 is given, you want to return the member. So you test that the parameter given is actually used for the call of the internal (memberDao) object.

So, at least call the ctl. with a real number instead of anyInt, preferably even replace all the anyInt() calls, since they don't actually improve your test case here, but actually reduce the quality of the test.

Using anyInt does not mean that the test proves that any int will work. WHAT ints to use is your job to know. For example, are negative ints allowed? Zero? etc.

**Edit:** Since it has been brought up in another answer... Yes, of course another possibility would be to "dumb down" the error message that it doesn't need the actual id. The question is: Is the error message important? Is the id there important? I would guess yes, but the it depends on the use case. So, IF the exact error message is important, you will have to verify the exact error message - and adjust your test if the error message gets changed. But that's totally ok, the tests are there to ensure a specific behaviour - if the exact error message is important, is it part of that specific behaviour and must be tested. And if this behaviour then changes, the job of the unit tests is to cry "Boo-Hoo, that method doesn't do what it's supposed to do anymore.". That's what unit tests are for. 
If the specific error mesage is not important but it is important that it contains the id, then you could verify against that (using `contains` or an `ArgumentCaptor`). 
If it's only important THAT an the error method is called, regardless of the actual message, then verify against anyString() and be done with it.

Comment: "For example, there could be an error in `ctl.cardSwiped`" I didn't even think of that! That's a good point. I just wanted the test to show that any integer input is fine, but there's actually a few edge cases where that's not true. A negative int would fail as well. Ok definitely the wrong approach. Thanks for the explanation, I was approaching the problem from the wrong direction.

Comment: Finding the edge cases is always the tricky thing to do, especially in mathematical problems, of course, but also here. Mutation testing can be used to identify them, but that would be overkill here, probably ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`Answer` interface can be used to interact with the mock and the parameters with which its methods are invoked.

```
doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
    public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        String msg = (String) args[0];
        //Asserting the arguments with which mock method was invoked
        Assert.assertEquals("expected", msg);
        return null;
    }
}).when(ui).displayErrorMessage(any(String.classs));
```

Comment: @Florian: Because, in this way, you keep the message formatting logic inside your business code only. You don't decide in the test case how the output message is generated. In your approach, the formatting logic is duplicated in the test case as well. So, if you change your formatting logic, you do the same changes test cases as well.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. You are comparing the error message with the constant String "expected" there, so it will always fail...? How does that allow you to check for the correct message? One could argue that the only important point is, that the error message contains the id or something like this and thus not check for equality but with contains, but that doesn't need an Answer, too. Additionally, moving your asserts into your answer will make the resulting error harder to read.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz: "expected" means the string which you wan't to compare the result with. Regarding the point that "important point is, that the error message contains the id or something like this", it is based on the assumption that message contains id. Suppose later on, you change the entire formatting logic such that it doesn't contain any id. In that case, all those changes are to be made in test cases as well.

Comment: Yes, if you make changes to your specs, you need to change the tests, too. Sorry, don't get your point. Coding in a way to make your code testable is great. But that does not mean to remove functionality. In this case, I would expect the error message to contain the id. To remove that from the message would be dumbing down the code, not improve it. And of course, IF you think that way, then you still don't need the `Answer`, since a simple `verify` will be enough to test the method call vs. `"expected"` without moving the assert into some anonymous class.